# NotesJSONArray or NotesJSONNavigator can't parse empty values properly

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have experienced an issue after we recently upgraded Domino server from 11.0.0 to 11.0.1 FP2.
The issue is related to parsing JSON with native NotesJSON classes, see snippet below.

**1. NotesJSONArray**

```
content = |[{"param1":"value1", "param2":""},{"param1":"", "param2":"AAA"},{"param1":"", "param2":""}]|

Set jsonNav = session.Createjsonnavigator(Content)
        
Set jsonEl = jsonNav.Getfirstelement()
While Not jsonEl Is Nothing
    Set jsonObj = jsonEl.Value
    Set jsonEl2 = jsonObj.Getfirstelement()
    While Not jsonEl2 Is Nothing
        Print jsonEl2.Name
        Print "<br/>"
        Print jsonEl2.value
        Set jsonEl2 = jsonObj.Getnextelement()
    Wend
    
    Set jsonEl = jsonNav.Getnextelement
wend
```

The output got some broken characters. It only occurs in case if param1 or param2 have empty value. I wonder if it's an issue in Domino or I do something wrong? In most of cases it does not work but sometimes it actually works.

```
param1
value1
param2
param1
Ê$■ · ¦¦.¦¦Çã
param2
AAA
param1
$P■ · ¦¦.¦¦░
param2
```

**2. NotesJSONNavigator**

```
content = |{"param1":"","param2":"","param3":""}|

Set jsonNav = session.Createjsonnavigator(Content)
Set jsonEl = jsonNav.Getfirstelement()
While Not jsonEl Is Nothing
    msgbox jsonEl.Name & " = " & jsonEl.value
    
    Set jsonEl = jsonNav.Getnextelement()
Wend
```

That gives pretty similar results, f.x.

```
param3 = xm■ chemas/domino_11_0_1.dtd
```

Environment:
1 Domino server 11.0.1 FP2, Windows. Same issue on client Notes 11.0.1. FP2

When I do:

```
MsgBox jsonNav.Stringify()
```

That show proper string.

Any idea would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted HCL and they confirmed it's a regression on 11.0.1 FP2.

It will be fixed within next release, but so far no solution to that issue.

You can follow the issue by this link:

https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0084703&sys_kb_id=4157fd171b8c6810a2f48661cd4bcbb5